# php variable data output blank

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a php page ("index.php") that has a variable "$vid".

What I also have is this include file ("vars.php") that is included within "index.php", that sets $video to $vid when filled.  "vars.php" is then included in a php file("cta_settings.php") that when called by my flash swf, queries my sql server database to retrieve a listing and form an XML DomDocument.

Vars.php consists of the following, ad is included in the page that sets the "$video" variable:

Vars.php

```
<?php
if(isset($vid))
{   
    $video = $vid;
    echo "CTA Vars Video: " . $video;   
}
?>
```

cta_settings.php:

```
<?php
include("vars.php");

echo "Settings Video Number: " . $video;
?>
```

The echo clearly has the variable present because the value is seen on the page.

My issue is that in cta_settings.php the variable "$video" is blank.  I have used firebug and in the NET panel under Response all I see is "Settings Video Number: ".  I have also tried to create the XML file and have the swf call that.  When doing this, the file is written, but the variables I need are blank within their nodes.  I thought that it would have something to do with the output of the variable seeing that I can echo it but cannot see it within the firebug response panel.

I have tried strval(), changing header type (text/plain), globals, and even sessions.  I have spent a good 3 days trying to figure this one out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Firebug can't see your PHP (server-side) internal code, thus not know your variables. When you `include()` your variables run out of scope (http://www.php.net/language.variables.scope.php). Try to use functions if you want to pass them onto the 'includer' PHP-file.

Comment: Have you tried using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)?

Comment: Where does `$vid` come from?  Do you see "CTA Vars Video:" in your output?  It would seem that it's not making it into your `if (isset($vid))`

Comment: `cta_settings.php` has no `$vid`, ergo no `$video`?

Comment: You haven't shown that `$vid` is set. Is it?

Comment: If you install xdebug you will see the problem immediately most likely. As for it being set .... http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

It being set does not guarantee it will have a printable value. Try doing a var_export($video).